# android to receive a string from java server after successful connection and sending of message

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

(edited my question) i have a working android client which sends data to java server every second. Simple java server receives the data continuously with no problem. What i want is the android client to receive reply from server for successful transmission (of data from android to server) and i want that reply to be put in a text view. I have tried inserting some code but can't figure out how i can receive and show the "OK" in the client text view. (By the way the network portion implements the async task)

```
   public static void connect(String name, int port)
        throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{

    s = new Socket(name, port);
    out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
     input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
}

/**
 * Sends a string message to the server.
 * 
 * @param msg
 *            The message to be sent.
 * @throws IOException
 */
 public static void send(String msg) throws IOException
{
    if (!s.isClosed() && msg != null)
    {
        out.println(msg);

        out.close();                                
    }


}
 public static String receive() throws IOException
 {
     if (!s.isClosed())
     {
         result1 = input.readLine();

            out.close(); 
            input.close(); 
            s.close();


     }
    return result1;


 }

  //Used for receiving notifications from the LocationManager when the location has changed

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String txt = "Latitude:" + loc.getLatitude() + "/nLongitude:" + loc.getLongitude();
        Log.i("GeoLocation", "My current location is:\n " + txt);
        tv.setText("My current location is:\n" + txt);
        String msg=loc.getLongitude() + "\n" + loc.getLatitude() + "\n"
        + loc.getTime();
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);  
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        //determines if the location is within a designated area (rectangle)
        double lat0 = 14.609794;
        double long0 = 120.986018;
        double lat1 = 14.608966;
        double long1 = 120.986037;
        double lat2 = 14.609031;
        double long2 = 120.984991;
        double lat3 = 14.609877;
        double long3 = 120.985069;
        double rel1 = (loc.getLongitude()- long0)*(lat1 - lat0)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat0)*(long1-long0));
        double rel2 = (loc.getLongitude()- long1)*(lat2 - lat1)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat1)*(long2-long1));
        double rel3 = (loc.getLongitude()- long2)*(lat3 - lat2)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat2)*(long3-long2));
        double rel4 = (loc.getLongitude()- long3)*(lat0 - lat3)- ((loc.getLatitude()-lat3)*(long0-long3));

        // if yes, it will connect to server and send the location and timestamp

       if (rel1 >= 0 && rel2 >= 0 && rel3 >= 0 && rel4 >= 0 )
        {
           tv1.setText("Location is inside the road network...");
           new connectSend().execute(msg);  



          // new receiveString().execute();
           }


        else
        {
            tv1.setText("Current location is outside the road network");

        }
        }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public class connectSend extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String result;

            try
            {
            connect("192.168.10.191", 7774);
            send(msg[0]);
            result = "Sending is SUCCESSFUL ";
            receive();
            publishProgress(result1);

            }

            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = "Sending NOT SUCCESSFUL ";
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = "Sending NOT SUCCESSFUL ";
            }

            return result;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... result1) 
        {
                super.onProgressUpdate(result1);
                tv3.setText(result1[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tv2.setText(result);

}}    

}
```

}

In case needed below is a simple java server which receives the data through a socket and reply if reception is successful

```
class ChatServer {
private static int port = 1234; /* port to listen on */

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

    class ClientConn implements Runnable {
        private Socket client;

        ClientConn(Socket client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        public void run() {
            BufferedReader in = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            try {
                /* obtain an input stream to this client ... */
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            client.getInputStream()));
                /* ... and an output stream to the same client */
                out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
                return;
            }

            String msg;
            try {
                /* loop reading messages from the client, 
                 * output to stdin and send back an "OK" back */
                while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client says: " + msg);
                    out.println("OK");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    ServerSocket server = null;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port); /* start listening on the port */
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket client = null;
    while(true) {
        try {
            client = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        /* start a new thread to handle this client */
        Thread t = new Thread(new ClientConn(client));
        t.start();
    }
}
```

}

---

I got it now. I had two out.close();. I removed one of them and it worked now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you have implemented only one direction of the socket communication. The client currently only sends data and the server only receives data. What you want is to open an input stream on the client and an output stream on the server, too. After sending the command to the server the client would then read from the input stream and the server would write to the output stream after reading in the command from the client. Very similar to the communication you have currently implemented, but in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes. That's what i'm figuring out right now. Already the whole day doing trial and error on additional code. Can you please help me where can i insert the code needed in the android client. I read in other pages that i need to use the code                      DataIntputStream input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream()) ;
byte[] b  =  new byte[1024]
input.read(b) ; 
String inputString  = new String(b) ;    Is it correct? How should i do it?

Comment: Your server already returns an "OK" after every line, the clients sends. Have a look at the server. It opens an input and an output stream. Same thing has to be done for the client. The client should then read from the input stream (, which you have to open additionally to the output stream) directly after calling the send method.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have edited my question showing the additional code i tried which failed. Appreciate your input henrik.